# How does Ubuntu handle deadlock situations?

Tags: deadlock

I need links to some documentation which states how Ubuntu handles [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), which method does it apply?

Please note am asking this question as am a new user regarding the os and therefore really confused google is not helpful

EDIT-- additional details

(kernal and user space in general

how to compare linux with an ms windows)

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the Linux Kernel (and by proxy Ubuntu) ignores deadlocks. They happen so infrequently that the cost to manage them (monitoring, resolution) far exceeds the benefit. The least costly way to manage them is to simply ignore them (Whereas other applications like databases run in to Deadlocks more frequently, Linux does not).

Comment: I'm interested to know where you get this impression.  I'm not questioning you, I'd just like to know.

Comment: u mean, linux doesnot have any mechanism to handle dead locks!

Comment: Right - which is why I mentioned the Linux Kernel in my post

Comment: @aperson This is simply what's been documented from the Linux Kernel team. I don't recall the source though. It is from research I performed a few months back for my company

Answer (score 2):

Deadlocks can occur in lot of different situations and may or may not be handled. If they are handled, they are handled in different ways. In order to received a specific answer, you would have to specify a particular area (i.e. networking, memory management, or specific applications). Is your question more academic, or do you have a particular problem?

Comment: my question is theoretical and areas are kernel and user space, mainly kernel space.. help..